# Batch decrypt folders while keeping directory structure?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have thousands of encrypted files in the directory `D:\Data`. They are of different file extensions. For example `D:\Data\a.txt` and `D:\Data\Sub\b.jpg`.

I also have a `decrypt.exe`. The usage is:

> decrypt <input file> [output file=input] [option]

The option I use is `-o`.

Now I need to decrypt all the files to `D:\Data_2` with the original folder structure.

Can someone tell me how this task could be done with a Windows batch file?

I know little about Windows batch file coding and therefore don't know where to start.

Comment: Seems to me this can be handled with a one-liner from a cmd console.  `for /r "d:\Data" %I in (*) do @decrypt "%~fI" "%~dI\Data_2%~pnxI" -o` or whatever the syntax for `decrypt` is.  You'll end up with your files in `D:\Data_2\Data`, but it's up to you whether the simplicity is worth the price.  Anyway, in a cmd console, `for /?` for more details about the `/r` switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a commented batch code for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SourcePath=D:\Data"
set "TargetPath=D:\Data_2"

rem If the batch file was started with a string as
rem parameter, interpret this string as source path.
if not "%~1" == "" set "SourcePath=%~1"

rem If the batch file was started with one more string
rem as parameter, interpret this string as target path.
if not "%~2" == "" set "TargetPath=%~2"

rem Remove backslash at end of source and target path
rem in case of being specified with a backslash at end.
if "%SourcePath:~-1%" == "\" set "SourcePath=%SourcePath:~0,-1%"
if "%TargetPath:~-1%" == "\" set "TargetPath=%TargetPath:~0,-1%"

rem Determine length of source path by finding out at which
rem position in source path there is no more character.
set "PathLength=1"
:GetPathLength
if not "!SourcePath:~%PathLength%,1!" == "" (
    set /A PathLength+=1
    goto GetPathLength
)

rem Process each file not having hidden or system attribute set and
rem decrypt it to the target path relative to source path. The relative
rem path is determined by removing from full path of current file the
rem first PathLength characters and the last character which is the
rem directory separator (backslash).
for /R "%SourcePath%" %%I in (*) do (
    set "RelativePath=%%~dpI"
    set "RelativePath=!RelativePath:~%PathLength%,-1!"
    md "%TargetPath%!RelativePath!" 2>nul
    decrypt.exe "%%I" "%TargetPath%!RelativePath!\%%~nxI" -o
)
endlocal
```

It is possible to test this batch file with a dry run by inserting left of `md` and `decrypt.exe` the command `echo` to just output the lines which really modify something on storage media.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... for an explanation of `%~1` and `%~2`.
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

And read also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` used to redirect the error message output by command `md` to handle **STDERR** on directory already existing to the device **NUL** to suppress it.

See also [Microsoft's command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) and SS64's [A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/).